# Linq query combine two or three expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, lambda

I am getting lineCount, boolean value and lastline from the text file with the below queries

```
 private void ReadFile(FileInfo[] TXTFiles, out int totalLineCount, out bool result, out string footerContent)
 {
     totalLineCount = File.ReadLines(TXTFiles[0].FullName).Count();
     result = File.ReadLines(TXTFiles[0].FullName).Last().StartsWith(fileFooterIdentify);
     footerContent = File.ReadLines(TXTFiles[0].FullName).Last();
 }
```

here I am reading file for three times it will little bit hit the performance us there any possible to combine those three lines into single expression and 
looking to make single read action for file ..

Could any one help me on this how to make single expression among the above.

many thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps I didn't fully understand your requirements, but if it is the performance that worries you, I would suggest the following:

```
private void ReadFile(FileInfo[] TXTFiles, out int totalLineCount, out bool result, out string footerContent)
 {
     var fileContents = File.ReadLines(TXTFiles[0].FullName);
     totalLineCount = fileContents.Count();
     result = fileContents.Last().StartsWith(fileFooterIdentify);
     footerContent = fileContents.Last();
 }
```

From what I know, transforming it into a single expression will neither additionally improve your performance, nor will make it more readable.

**EDIT:**
If you were looking for the way to *iterate* over your `FileInfo` array, I can suggest the following expression:

```
var fileReadInfo = TXTFiles.Select(file =>
{
    var fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);
    return new Tuple<int, bool, string>(fileContents.Count(),
        fileContents.Last().StartsWith(fileFooterIdentify), fileContents.Last());
});
```

Though I would recommend you to create some class to store all information about file, instead of using `Tuple`.

Comment: @EnigmaState glad I could help.

Comment: I am not able to get values on fileReadInfo ... intellisense  is not showing anything about count and remaining things .. how can i use the fileReadinfo ...could u pls tell

Comment: @EnigmaState in that particular example I used `Tuple<int, bool, string>` to collect all required data, so fileReadInfo is an `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, bool, string>>`. You can do something like `foreach (var entry in fileReadInfo)` and then access collected data with properties `entry.Item1`, `entry.Item2` and `entry.Item3`. For further information about how to use tuples you can go there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just save the result of the file read as an array:

```
private void ReadFile(FileInfo[] TXTFiles, out int totalLineCount, out bool result, out string footerContent)
 {
     string[] lines = File.ReadLines(TXTFiles[0].FullName);
     totalLineCount = lines.Count();
     result = lines.Last().StartsWith(fileFooterIdentify);
     footerContent = lines.Last();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of `File.ReadLines` into a local variable and use that one

```
private void ReadFile(FileInfo[] TXTFiles, out int totalLineCount, out bool result, out string footerContent)
 {
     var content = File.ReadLines(TXTFiles[0].FullName);
     totalLineCount = content.Count();
     footerContent = content.Last();
     result = footerContent.StartsWith(fileFooterIdentify);
 }
```

That will read the file only two times.

To have only a single read action change to

```
private void ReadFile(FileInfo[] TXTFiles, out int totalLineCount, out bool result, out string footerContent)
{
    var content = File.ReadLines( TXTFiles[0].FullName );
    totalLineCount = 0;
    foreach ( var row in content )
    {
        totalLineCount++;
        footerContent = row;
    }
    result = footerContent.StartsWith( fileFooterIdentify );
}
```